# How can an mlflow model be scaled to serve more requests?

Tags: multithreading, gunicorn, mlflow

I would like to have multiple instances of my MLFlow model running in parallel but hidden behind a common the same endpoint/port so it's not visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Increase the number of workers for mlflow serve [-w flag](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-models-serve-w) with the number of workers
2. Use cloud platform [link](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#deploy-a-python-function-model-on-microsoft-azure-ml)
3. Serve your model on [Kubernetes with kubeflow](https://medium.com/scientya/share-ml-with-kubeflow-and-mlflow-71ec13ebf9c9)